# Issuing multiple ssl certificates

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, lets-encrypt

I was having some issues routing www to a non www url in nginx and i ended up deleting the entire letsencrypt folder. Now I am getting a CAA iusse failure when trying to run certbot again. Is there anyway to recover my keys or to wipe it clean to start again?

Comment: Just request a new certificate instead of a renewal.

Comment: I tried, but I keep getting CAA issuing failure

Comment: Do you have CAA records on your domain? https://letsencrypt.org/docs/caa/

Comment: `Detail: CAA record for www.example.com prevents issuance` and no I do not

Comment: Can you give us the domain in question?

Comment: Then you need to fix or remove the CAA record.

Comment: @MichaelHampton ok i will try resetting everything and revert to noc CAA